# Getting the coefficients of an expression with Solve

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, symbolic

I have a very lengthy expression (600+ terms) with derivatives of several functions, which I want to write in a compact way. I would like to get the coefficients of terms I know exist in this expression, i.e. I want Mathematica to take something like:

```
f = -Derivative[0, 1][g][x, y]^2 + (2*Derivative[0, 1][g][x, y]^2 + 
   2*g[x, y]*Derivative[0, 2][g][x, y])/3 - Derivative[1, 0][g][x, y]^2 + 
 (2*Derivative[1, 0][g][x, y]^2 + 2*g[x, y]*Derivative[2, 0][g][x, y])/3
```

and eventually give me the right information to write this as
$$f=\frac{1}{3}\nabla^2(g(x,y)^2)-\partial_ig(x,y)\partial_ig(x,y)$$

Using `Coefficient` is not an option because there might be terms in common between different elements (e.g., asking for $\partial_ig(x,y)\partial_ig(x,y)$ will give me 1 instead of the sought -1).  I have tried tackling this by running `Simplify` with assumptions:

```
Simplify[f, digdig == Derivative[1, 0][g][x, y]^2+Derivative[0, 1][g][x, y]^2 && Δg2 == Laplacian[g[x,y]^2,{x,y}]]
```

which gives me, correctly,  `-digdig + 1/3 Δg2`. However, for a very long expression, this is super slow and not very beautiful (since I have to define over 20 different terms with different variable names).

So, I was looking for an alternative using `Solve`:

```
Solve[f == a Laplacian[g[x,y]^2,{x,y}]+b(Derivative[1, 0][g][x, y]^2+Derivative[0, 1][g][x, y]^2),{a,b}]
```

I would expect this to give me `{{a->1/3,b->-1}}`, but instead, it returns `{{b-> the expression solved for b, including an a}}`.

Is there a way to force `Solve` to give me a transformation rule involving *all* variables I provide it on the LHS? Or do you know an alternative way to find the coefficients of such an expression which is maybe faster than Simplify?

Comment: I think you are looking for `SolveAlways`, as you want constant values that are valid for all values of x,y.

Comment: Weirdly, ```SolveAlways``` refuses to evaluate when run on a longer expression of this kind.